# Android Resources - Array of Objects

Tags: android, arrays, object, resources

I have an array of objects and want to represent them in an resource array.
The class is defined like this:

```
class MyItem{
    private int id;
    private int price;
    private String name;
    private String desc;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

not sure about the syntax... but I tried this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="Category01">
        <item>
            <array>
                <item name="name">Name</item>
                <item name="desc">Description</item>
                <item name="imageId">0000000</item>
                <item name="price">100</item>
            </array>
        </item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

not working... how to represent my array of objects in resources ??  thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to clean up your XML: you've got two arrays representing the same thing. Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="Category01">
        <item name="name">Name</item>
        <item name="desc">Description</item>
        <item name="imageId">0000000</item>
        <item name="price">100</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Now, the question whether you can create a resource array of POJO's, It is THEORETICALLY possible. If it isn't, in your getters and setters, convert all `int`'s to `Strings` using `Integer.toString(int)` and `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Comment: That way wouldnt each item of the array be a field of my object ?

Comment: OK, do you want them to be fields or XML? If you want these "variables" defined in an XML resource, then they won't be fields.